# Plugin DSL method 'request' is deprecated. Use '$self->app->request' instead'

Tags: perl, dancer

In perl, I am using Dancer 2 frame work, and using this plugin

```
use Dancer2::Plugin::Deferred;
use Dancer2::Plugin::Locale::Wolowitz;
```

For statements like below:

```
my $method = request->method();

my $params = request->params;
```

I am getting following warnings on console:

```
Plugin DSL method 'request' is deprecated. Use '$self->app->request' instead'.
```

Please give your recommendations to solve it out, I am not sure which of these two modules are causing this.

thanks

Comment: I think you are using either the Dancer or Dancer2 framework, or the Mojolicious framework, but I cannot be sure without seeing your code.

Comment: Thanks for welcome, I have edited my question, hopefully it makes sense now. If you are not getting it, please let me know, I may modify it and make it clearer.

Comment: Which version of Dancer2? Please run `perl -MDancer2\ 99` on the terminal, including the space after the backslash.

Comment: I cannot reproduce on Dancer2 0.206000 and Dancer2::Plugin::Deferred 0.007017. Are you using something else as well? Please [edit] again and include a [mcve].

Comment: Its 0.206000 on running this `perl -MDancer2\ 99 ` I am getting following error:

Comment: `Dancer2 version 99 required--this is only version 0.206000 at /usr/local/share/perl5/Dancer2.pm line 17.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted.`

Comment: That error message was expected. This is the fastest way to get the version number.

Comment: So we have the same D2 version, but I don't get the error. Please make a full program I can run. Anyway, the obvious solution is to do what it says in the warning and use `$self->app->request` instead. ;)

Comment: Actually we are calling functions as 
` get '/testModule/testSubModule/:test_id/update' => \&test_controller::testMethod; `

now in testMethod if we try to get
 `resuest->params; `
we are getting values but warnings too -;p,,

Comment: Please make a stand-alone program to demonstrate the warning. One route, as simple as possible.

Comment: and we cant use $self there.. as if we call functions by using `::`

Comment: The colons have nothing to do with method calls. Dancer2 will always call route handlers as methods and pass along `$self`. That's just how it works. It doesn't matter if you provide a fresh anonymous sub or a reference to an existing sub by name to the `get` DSL helper.

Comment: I am getting this error: 
`error @2018-10-29 01:33:10> Route exception: Can't call method "app" on an undefined value at /foo/foo_controller.pm line 227. in /usr/local/share/perl5/Dancer2/Core/App.pm l. 1473
`

Comment: we are unable to get this `$self` object there.

Comment: its undef there:

Comment: `
$VAR1 = undef;`

Comment: You need to show the code you've used. Run my example. Does it work for you? Then apply the technique to your program. If mine works and yours doesn't you are doing something wrong. I can't help you if I can't see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dancer2 is mostly object-oriented. It always passes a `$self` to your route handlers. The warning is pretty clear. You should not use that DSL keyword, but instead access the request via `$self->app`.

You need to grab `$self` from the argument list of your route handlers. It doesn't matter whether you use an anonymous sub or a reference to a named sub, in the same package or any other package.

```
use Dancer2;

get '/' => \&main::foo;

sub foo {
  my $self = shift;
  return $self->app->request->params;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @simbabque
It is working fine for **get** calls but we are getting error in ajax calls, we are calling this function as:
`ajax '/_updateTest' =>  \&main::foo;`

Error is : `error @2018-10-29 06:48:42> Route exception: Can't call method "app" on an undefined value at`

Comment: @I_G again, please provide a [mcve]. I can't help without knowing all the facts. Right now you are just wasting both our time if you don't tell me everything. Nothing is worse than guessing in IT.

Comment: similar is the case for `ajax ['post'] => '/test/testCall' =>  \&main::foo;`

Comment: `use Dancer2;

get '/' => \&main::foo; #working fine

# $self object is undef for following type of calls

ajax '/_updateTest' => \&main::foo; 

ajax ['post'] => '/test/testCall' => \&main::foo;

sub foo {
  my $self = shift;
  return $self->app->request->params;
}`

Comment: we have tested with your provided code, just changes the way of call, I mean ajax and post.

@simbabque, you may please test the above code provided by you by updating the calling way

at my end there is a routing file in which I change the calling methodology.

Comment: @I_G ok, NOW I can reproduce it. You should have said that you have the AJAX plugin from the start. The plugins you showed in the question are completely unrelated.

Comment: @I_G indeed, the ::Ajax plugin doesn't allow this. I think that's a bug.  https://metacpan.org/source/CROMEDOME/Dancer2-Plugin-Ajax-0.300000/lib/Dancer2/Plugin/Ajax.pm#L46. There is no evidence that this has been possible, and the last release of ::Ajax is over two years ago. I will file a bug report.

Comment: @I_G I am currently filing a ticket on github. Feel free to grab it and supply a patch. The D2 maintainers are usually quick with accepting those, especially as we've still got a few days of Hacktoberfest left.

Comment: I proposed a fix.

Comment: @I_G my fix has been released, see https://metacpan.org/pod/Dancer2::Plugin::Ajax for version 0.400000.

Comment: @I_G you're welcome. Please note I am not affiliated with the Dancer team, although I am friends with some of them. In the future, feel free to suggest such changes yourself. They always welcome the help! :)

Comment: That's great! We are happy to find such response from Dancer 2.